# Javascript not checking radio button

Tags: javascript, html

The following script is not checking working when testing the radio button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function checkButton(){
          if(document.getElementById('Revise').checked = true){
              alert("hello");
          }
      }
      </script>
```

The html code is:

```
<form:radiobutton id= "Revise" value="Revise" name="status" path="status"></form:radiobutton>
```

Do i need to call the function/or place it in the body?

Comment: You have a typo: `.checked = true` should be `.checked == true` or just `.checked`. You are using the assignment operator instead of the equality operator. Also, I don't see anywhere where you call the `checkButton` function.

Comment: You have a typo in `document.getElementById('Revise').checked = true` row. Use a comparison sign (`==` or `===`) instead of just assigning (`=`).

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC? It appears as so with the formatting of your form radio button.

Comment: @ChrisCruz yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most people have mentioned within their comments, you either need to 
write 
`if(document.getElementById('Revise').checked === true)`(newbie way)

or

write `if(document.getElementById('Revise').checked)` (pro way)

Also, you haven't invoked the function "checkButton", this is how you do it:

```
<form> <input type="radio" id= "Revise" value="Revise" name="status" path="status" onclick="checkButton()"> Click Me!! </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works fine now :)

Comment: you're more than Welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code is not working because you defined a function (checkButton) that never make a call to, thus it is never executed.

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do but you should avoid using in-line javascript.

If you are trying to run the alert when the radio button is clicked then add an click event listener on the radio.

```
document.getElementById('Revise').addEventListener('click',function() {
     alert('Hello');
});
```

[JSFindle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/wcxL9x4q/)

If you are trying to define a function called checkButton that checks your radio and shows an alert then your function would be defined like this:

```
function checkButton() {
    document.getElementById('Revise').checked = true;
    alert('Hello');
}
```

[JSFindle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/k578epf5/)

And then you would just invoke checkButton() on your trigger.